# How to produce syn::Meta?

Tags: rust, macros, abstract-syntax-tree, attr

I am "parsing" AST (namely, `DeriveInput`) produced by `parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput)` in my `derive` macros implementation.

I found a useful for my purposes type, enum `syn::Meta`.

It is, however, unclear how I construct the appropriate value of `syn::Meta` for a field of a struct that I apply attributes to:
`syn::Field::Attrs` contains `attrs: Vec<Attribute>` where `Attribute` contains `tokens: TokenStream` (that are inconvenient to deal with) instead of expected `syn::Meta`.

Maybe, I should convert `Vec<Attribute>` to or `TokenStream` to `syn::Meta`? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found (have searched for functions returning `Meta`):

[Here](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.Attribute.html#method.parse_meta):

> ```rust
> pub fn parse_meta(&self) -> Result<Meta>
> ```
>
> Available on
> crate feature parsing
> only.
>
> Parses the content of the attribute, consisting of the path and tokens, as a Meta if possible.
>
> *This function is available only if Syn is built with the "parsing" feature.)*